# Importing CSV to Django and settings not recognised

Tags: django, python-2.7, database-connection

So i'm getting to grips with Django, or trying to.  I have some code that isn't dependent on being called by the webpage - it's designed to populate the database with information.  Eventually it will be set up as a cron job to run overnight.  This is the first crack at it, which is to do an initial population (once I have that working, I'll move to an add structure, where only new records are pushed.)  I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.5 and Sqlite3.  When I run this code, I get

`Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

That seems fairly obvious, but I've spent a couple of hours now trying to work out how to adjust that setting.  How do I call / open a connection / whatever the right terminology is here?  I have a number of functions like this that will be scheduled jobs, and this has been frustrating me all afternoon.

```
import urllib2
import csv
import requests

from django.db import models
from gmbl.models import Match   

master_data_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/E0.csv", "GET")
data = list(tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(master_data_file, delimiter=','))

for row in data:
    current_match = Match(matchdate=row[1], 
        hometeam=row[2], 
        awayteam = row [3], 
        homegoals = row [4], 
        awaygoals = row[5],
        homeshots = row[10],
        awayshots = row[11],
        homeshotsontarget = row[12],
        awayshotsontarget = row[13],
        homecorners = row[16],
        awaycorners = row[17])
    current_match.save()
```

I had originally started out with http://django-csv-importer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but I had the same error, and the documentation doesn't make much sense trying to debug it.   When I tried calling settings.configure in the function, it said it didn't exist; presumably I had to import it, but couldn't make that work.

Comment: You need to import your settings and do a little extra setup, or define the import as a custom `manage.py` command.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226405/scripting-django has a good answer showing the full import and setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Django, and your project are in PYTHONPATH then you can do:

```
import urllib2
import csv
import requests
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from django.db import models
from yoursite import settings

setup_environ(settings)

from gmbl.models import Match   

master_data_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/E0.csv", "GET")
data = list(tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(master_data_file, delimiter=','))

# ... your code ...
```

Reference: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Hope it helps!

Comment: That does help a bit -but I've added the project into sys path a couple of times now and it doesn't seem to save/retain it.  So I do `import sys`, `sys.path` in terminal to check what's on the path, and then append the paths in - but it appears to be losing it, so guess I need to edit this in a settings file  - stupid question, but which one?    Muh.  

(This hasn't been helped by the fact I had two versions of Django on the machine, both 1.5 (the normal install and BitnamiStack for Django), which was complicating adding the right folders.  Jees.)