# Django settings for standalone

Tags: python, django, django-models

I asked this before, but I'm still stuck.  This script will end up being run as a cron job.
Previous question : [Importing CSV to Django and settings not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979597/importing-csv-to-django-and-settings-not-recognised)

I've skipped the actual code that imports the csvs, as that's not the problem.

```
import urllib2
import csv
import requests
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from django.db import models
from gmbl import settings

settings.configure(
    DEBUG = True,
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/Users/c/Dropbox/Django/mysite/mysite/db.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

)



#
from sys import path

sys.path.append("/Users/chris/Dropbox/Django/mysite/gmbl")

from django.conf import settings
```

This gives me the traceback: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
logout`

So I tried switching it around, and put settings.configure... etc before the `from django.db import models` line, but then it just said `"settings not defined"`

I've tried adding the

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from django.db import models
from yoursite import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

code suggested in the answer, but it still errors out on the from django.db import models section.  What am I missing, aside from something that seems super obvious to everyone else?

Comment: can you use a custom management command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales

Comment: What would that look like, though?  Set the can_import_settings to True, to get it to throw an error if it can't?  I'm not really sure what you're suggesting, sorry.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell er, what? dm03514 is suggesting that you use the instructions he linked to to write a custom manage.py command. With that, you have no need to explicitly configure settings.

Comment: Oh, write the standalone code as a custom command?  I thought he meant use that to sort the settings problem.  I'll give that a try later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone upvoted this question today, which was nice, and I thought I'd come back to it with the benefit of hindsight, because the answers above didn't help me. This is largely because I couldn't adequately explain what I was trying to do; thanks to those who tried to help me.

For other noobs coming to it, there were two problems.

The first was - I was trying to run this from the command line in the first instance (not stated in the question, so partly my fault.)  I wanted to run it from CLI to test it while I was building.  Eventually, I wrote it into the views.py` as a an admin page, so I could trigger it whenever I needed it.

THe answer is, in fact, 'make sure your file is on the Python path/inside your Django app' If you're coming to this new and want to run stuff from the command line, the now super-obvious-steps are:

If your structure is

```
/myproject 
    /app 
    /myproject
```

Save this as [a defined function](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html) in a module (i.e. `csvimportdoofer.py`).  Let's call the function 'foobar'.

cd into your Django project folder (the top level /myproject, where `manage.py` lives)

`python manage.py shell`

`from app.csvimportdoofer import foobar`

Now from the commandline I can just call `foobar()` whenever I want.

Honestly - the need to have the `app.csvimportdoofer` segment really threw me for ages, but mostly because [I hadn't worked with my own modules in python before coming to Django](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html).  Run before you can walk...

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'yoursite.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```

Then you can use your models.

```
from my_app.models import MyModel
all_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
```